# QMainWindow and ownership takeover policy

Tags: qt

I stumbled upon this in the documentation for `QMainWindow::setMenuBar(QMenuBar * menuBar)`:

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the menuBar pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.

Example code (in a method of a class deriving from `QMainWindow`):

```
QMenuBar * menuBar = new QMenuBar(this);
setMenuBar(menuBar) // <-- immediately transfer ownership
// use menuBar pointer to add actions, menus, and what not
```

Can I still rely on my local pointer to my `QMenuBar` after a call to `setMenuBar`? I mean, is it completely guaranteed?

When I delete my `QMainWindow` derived class, the `QMenuBar` object is also deleted because the `QMainWindow` is set as its parent when constructing it - but what policy lies in the later "ownership takeover" through `setMenuBar` other than a copy of reference/pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to use that pointer as long as the object that took ownership is alive.

The fact that `QMainWindow` "takes ownership" of the menu means that it will take care of deleting it when it is not needed anymore. This is very common for Qt, see the [Object Trees & Ownership](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) documentation.

That being said, your sample code could be rewritten like this:

```
QMenuBar *menu = menuBar();
```

This will [create an empty menu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) if necessary, so you don't have to worry about any transfer of ownership. Just call that member function whenever you need to act on the windows's menu bar.

Comment: I might just use your approach, seems cleaner. So my two-line code-example is redundant perhaps? If the constructor to QMenuBar receives the pointer to QMainWindow, would a later call to setMenuBar be necessary then?

Comment: If you use `menuBar()`, you don't need to `setMenuBar()`, the menu bar you get is already all good to go. You should use that unless the note about Mac OSX & menu sharing in that doc I linked concerns you.